# registerclientscriptblock on javascript callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

I have a javascript function that checks for lat long and runs on page load.  It  calls a page method with the lat long.  In the page method, I use RegisterClientScriptBlock to set a bunch of variables, and return a string of javascript to display a map that uses those variables.  The map loads, but I get an error that the variables its expecting are undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
    function check() {           
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var panelProg = $get('progress');
            panelProg.style.display = '';
            var panelProg = $get('map');
            panelProg.style.display = 'none';              
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {                   
                // Access them accordingly
                PageMethods.SetSession(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, callBack);
            });
        }
    }
    function callBack(result) {         
eval(result);
    }
</script>

 [WebMethod]
public static string SetSession(string latval, string longval)
{
    //does work, calls RegisterClientScriptBlock to set a bunch of array variables
   //var lats = new Array(); var longs = new Array(); etc...
    return "displaymap(" + latval + "," + longval + ");";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not gonna work because the PageMethod does not perform the Page cycle. I mean the page does not postback and the script is not rendered.

You can work around this by returning the script.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SetSession(string latval, string longval)
{
    var js = "lats = new Array(); var longs = new Array();"; //etc...
    js += "displaymap(" + latval + "," + longval + ");";
    return js;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the variables are still undefined. Is this because the displaymap function is in a separate file?